# Html + jquery: Need to display selected dropdown text in a tooltip using jquery tooltip plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display the text of selected option of a dropdown list in a tooltip. For this I'm using jquery's tooltip plugin.

```
<select name="dropdown" class="tooltip" title="this.text">
    <option value=1>Text1 </option>
    <option value=2>Text2</option>
```

**Edit:**
Code from comment below:

```
<select name="release_version" id="release_version" class="tooltip" title="this.text" onChange="updateBuildPath(this.value);">
    <option value="12.5" selected="selected">Snapper</option>
    <option value="12.1">R12SP1</option><option value="12">R12</option>
    <option value="11.2">R11.2 SP4</option>
</select>
```

Using this, I see the text `this.text` in the tooltip, but what I want is `text1` or `text2` based on selected option. Is there anyway we can assign the `title` to selected text of the dropdown?

Of course it is working fine, if I use `mouseover` instead of tooltip class. But I want to achieve this using jQuery tooltip only as it is used extensively in my website

```
<select name="dropdown" onmouseover="this.title=this.text">
    <option value=1>Text1 </option>
    <option value=2>Text2</option>
```

Thanks in advance,
Sreedhar.

Comment: can you show a code of your script parts of it or at least how you are doing it currently. if this helps then use `$('select[selected=selected]').attr('title')` to get the title of it and pass it as a variable which i think most tooltips should accept :)

Comment: Can you please paste your code here?

Comment: I also did post the code in my request, but i don't see it displayed propery. Anyway here is the code.    ===================<select name="release_version" id="release_version" class="tooltip" title="this.text" onChange="updateBuildPath(this.value);"><option value="12.5" selected="selected">Snapper</option><option value="12.1">R12SP1</option><option value="12">R12</option><option value="11.2">R11.2 SP4</option></select> =================                                                    So, what I'm seeing as a tooltip is "this.text" instead of the text of the selected option.

Comment: You need to format the code as code - there are multiple options available above the text area, one of them is for code formatting (the icon with two curly braces `{}`) - select your code and click that button to format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like this? You can see [a live demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/QDxSa/)

```
//add a tooltip for the select box
//with a custom bodyHandler to dynamically update the tooltip text
$("select").tooltip({
    left: 25,
    bodyHandler: function(){
                     return $('#release_version').attr('title');
                 }
});

//bind an event handler for the change event
//so that when a new option is selected, the title for the 
//select element can be updated
$('#release_version').bind('change', function(e){
    var newTitle='';
    $("#release_version option:selected")
        .each(function () {
                 newTitle+= $(this).text() + " ";
              });

    $(this).attr('title', newTitle);
});

//trigger the initial selection so that the text of the element marked as
//selected when the page loads will be selected when the page loads
$('#release_version').trigger('change');
```

The idea here is to bind to the `change` event on the `select` and then set it's `title` attribute to the `text` of the `option` element that was selected. You also need to provide a `bodyHandler` for `tooltip()` since you need the text of the tooltip to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do ...

$(element).bind("mouseover", function () {

```
    if ($(element)[0])
    {
        $(element)[0].title = $(element)[0].options[$(element)[0].selectedIndex].text;
    }       

});
```